# How to check ABOX consistency using Hermit Reasoner

Tags: ontology, consistency, owl-api, reasoning, hermit

I am trying to learn how to use properly the OWLAPI but i am getting some troubles:
i have an ontology which structures the activities (e.g. individual and social activities); my aim is to create an easy example of inconsistency in order to get used with this API: i want to state that soccer is an individual activity.
`IndividualActivity` is defined in Protegè as `Equivalent to (Activity and (hasActor exactly 1 Person))`.

```
/// PIECE OF CODE ///

    OWLDataFactory df = Singleton_Ontologia.getFactory();

    IRI soccerIRI=IRI.create(Singleton_Ontologia.getIribase(),"Soccer");
    IRI paoloIRI = IRI.create(Singleton_Ontologia.getIribase(),"Paolo");
    IRI marcoIRI = IRI.create(Singleton_Ontologia.getIribase(),"Marco");

    OWLNamedIndividual soccer = df.getOWLNamedIndividual(soccerIRI);
    OWLNamedIndividual paolo = df.getOWLNamedIndividual(paoloIRI);
    OWLNamedIndividual marco = df.getOWLNamedIndividual(marcoIRI);

    OWLClass person = df.getOWLClass(
            IRI.create(Singleton_Ontologia.getIribase()+"Person"));

    OWLClass individual_activity = df.getOWLClass(
            IRI.create(Singleton_Ontologia.getIribase()+"IndividualActivity"));

    OWLObjectProperty hasActor = df.getOWLObjectProperty(
            IRI.create(Singleton_Ontologia.getIribase()+"hasActor"));

    OWLClassAssertionAxiom assertionAxiom = df.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(individual_activity, soccer);
    OWLClassAssertionAxiom assertionAxiom2 = df.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(person, paolo);
    OWLClassAssertionAxiom assertionAxiom3 = df.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(person, marco);
    OWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom assertionAxiom4 = df.getOWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom(hasActor, soccer, paolo);
    OWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom assertionAxiom5 = df.getOWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom(hasActor, soccer, marco);

    Singleton_Ontologia.getManager().addAxiom(ontologiaattuale,assertionAxiom);
    Singleton_Ontologia.getManager().addAxiom(ontologiaattuale,assertionAxiom2);
    Singleton_Ontologia.getManager().addAxiom(ontologiaattuale,assertionAxiom3);
    Singleton_Ontologia.getManager().addAxiom(ontologiaattuale,assertionAxiom4);
    Singleton_Ontologia.getManager().addAxiom(ontologiaattuale,assertionAxiom5);

/// CONSISTENCY CHECK ///

System.out.println("Consistency:"+Singleton_Ontologia.getReasoner().isConsistent());
```

and here is the configuration of Hermit reasoner:

```
public static void configReasoner() {
    iribase = "http://webmind.dico.unimi.it/CARE/locont.owl#";
    Configuration config=new Configuration();
    config.ignoreUnsupportedDatatypes=true; 
    factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
    reasonerFactory = new ReasonerFactory();
    reasoner = reasonerFactory.createReasoner(ont,config);
}
```

I created the individuals Paolo and Marco in order to create more than 1 `Person` being `Actors` of `Soccer` but the `isConsistent()` method still returns true while i expected a false value.
In addition, i printed the ABOX content:

```
___________ABOX___________


/////////////////////// OBJECT number 1 ///////////////////////
ClassAssertion(<http://webmind.dico.unimi.it/CARE/locont.owl#IndividualActivity> <http://webmind.dico.unimi.it/CARE/locont.owl#Soccer>)

/////////////////////// OBJECT number 2 ///////////////////////
ClassAssertion(<http://webmind.dico.unimi.it/CARE/locont.owl#Person> <http://webmind.dico.unimi.it/CARE/locont.owl#Paolo>)

/////////////////////// OBJECT number 3 ///////////////////////
ObjectPropertyAssertion(<http://webmind.dico.unimi.it/CARE/locont.owl#hasActor> <http://webmind.dico.unimi.it/CARE/locont.owl#Soccer> <http://webmind.dico.unimi.it/CARE/locont.owl#Paolo>)

/////////////////////// OBJECT number 4 ///////////////////////
ObjectPropertyAssertion(<http://webmind.dico.unimi.it/CARE/locont.owl#hasActor > <http://webmind.dico.unimi.it/CARE/locont.owl#Soccer> <http://webmind.dico.unimi.it/CARE/locont.owl#Marco>)

/////////////////////// OBJECT number 5 ///////////////////////
ClassAssertion(<http://webmind.dico.unimi.it/CARE/locont.owl#Person> <http://webmind.dico.unimi.it/CARE/locont.owl#Marco>)

___________END_ABOX___________
```

Honestly, i can't understand where my error is, may anyone help me?

Comment: Open world assumption. Individuals must be declared different, otherwise there is always a model where all your individuals are `sameAs` each other and the `exactly 1` restriction holds.

Comment: It seems that the `OWLDifferentIndividualsAxiom` isn't sufficient to solve the problem

Comment: Update: i recreated the same issue on Protegè and it worked, i mean, it says it is inconsistent as i would expect; that means that the problem is in Java, maybe i am doing wrong something else?

Comment: In the code you're making changes to the ontology after the reasoner is created. You need to flush the reasoner after the changes are made or it won't see the updates.

Comment: Ok! It finally worked!  Ignazio, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify that Marco and Paolo are different individuals. Without this axiom nothing prevents them to be the same one and keep the ontology consistent.

Comment: i did what you said through the `OWLDifferentIndividualsAxiom` but it says it's still consistent...

Comment: See my other comment.